# How to sort folders based on content in a file within them

Tags: php, sorting, directory

I'm working on a script in PHP which presents documents that's stored within a directory tree.

My directory tree looks somewhat like this:

```
* mainfolder1
    + subfolder1
        - subsubfolder1
        - subsubfolder2
    + subfolder2
        - subsubfolder3
        - subsubfolder4
```

Within each `subsubfolder` there is a file called `data.dat` that contains a *number*

I want to create an array that sorts these directories based on the number in `data.dat`

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: have you considered using that number in the directory name?

Comment: This very similar question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668637/php-sort-directories-by-contents

Comment: rather inefficient to do this frequently, you should consider storing the sort order else where

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) class to go through the main dir, then the [RegexIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.regexiterator.php) to filter the results. After that is just a matter of sorting an array the way you want.

Here's an example:

```
<?php 

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'));
$dataFiles = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/data.dat$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
$directories = array();

foreach($dataFiles as $name => $object){
    $directories[dirname($name)] = (int) file_get_contents($name);
}

asort($directories);
print_r(array_keys($directories));
```