# Sort the file names either ascending or descending order

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui-sortable

i have another question. I have the text files stored in the local document folder. i was able to display the file names in ascending order. but i want to know how to sort it in descending order using php. thanks. i want to give the user the ability to sort the files when they click a button.

Comment: just type in your browser address bar: `php sort reverse order`. It is really simple

Comment: good god, if i have not thought of that, would i post it here?

Comment: I think your question can be solved here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884974/sort-and-display-directory-list-alphabetically-using-opendir-in-php

Answer (score 1):

If your filenames stored within array, you might try this:

`array_reverse($filenames)`

UPD:

You may use **[scandir](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php)**, if they are not:

`scandir($path, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING)`

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually the textfiles are not stored in the array that's why i am having trouble sorting them out. i already used that function, to no avail.

Comment: Then store them in an array, and use it.

Comment: why don`t you put them to array before output? `scandir($dir, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING)` might help otherwise.