# PHP Directory, subdirectory and file Listing default sort order

Tags: php, file, function, directory, subdirectory

i want to list all directory, sub-directory and files using php.

i have tried following code. it returns all the directory, sub directory and files but it's not showing in correct order.

for ex:default order  is 1dir, 2dir, 7dir, 8dir while in browser it shows  1dir, 8dir, 7dir, 2dir which is not correct.

code:

```
       function createDir($path = '.')
       {
     if ($handle = opendir($path))
             {
               echo "<ul>";

      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
      {



   if (is_dir($path.$file) && $file != '.' && $file !='..') {
            printSubDir($file, $path);
         }
               else if ($file != '.' && $file !='..'){
         $allowed = array('pdf','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','jpg','png','gif','mp4','avi','3gp','flv','mov','PDF','DOC','DOCX','XLS','XLSX','JPG','PNG','GIF','MP4','AVI','3GP','FLV','MOV','html','HTML','css','CSS','js','JS');
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   if(in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
   $queue[] = $file;

 }
  }

   }

   printQueue($queue, $path);
  echo "</ul>";
    }
   }

       function printQueue($queue, $path)
            {

          sort($queue);
           foreach ($queue as $file)
        {
                  //printFile($file, $path);
       }
       }

        function printFile($file, $path) {

 echo "<li><a href=\"".$path.$file."\" target='_blank'>$file</a></li>";

             }

            function printSubDir($dir, $path)
        {
         echo "<li><span class=\"toggle\">$dir</span>";
        createDir($path.$dir."/");
     echo "</li>";
   }

         createDir($path);
    ?>
```

need help to fix the code and display the direcotry , subdirectory and files in correct order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884974/sort-and-display-directory-list-alphabetically-using-opendir-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem during listing a directory files. But I have used [DirectoryLister](http://www.directorylister.com/)
This code is very useful. You can list out your files easily.

You can implement it by following steps.

1. Download and extract Directory Lister
2. Copy resources/default.config.php to resources/config.php
3. Upload index.php and the resources folder to the folder you want listed
4. Upload additional files to the same directory as index.php

I hope this might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looping the array and printing each directory:

```
public function dirtree($dir, $regex='', $ignoreEmpty=false) {

    if (!$dir instanceof DirectoryIterator) {
        $dir = new DirectoryIterator((string)$dir);
    }

    $dirs  = array();
    $files = array();
    foreach ($dir as $node) {
        if ($node->isDir() && !$node->isDot()) {
            // print_r($node);
            $tree = dirtree($node->getPathname(), $ignoreEmpty);
                // print"<pre>";print_r($tree);
            if (!$ignoreEmpty || count($tree)) {
                $dirs[$node->getFilename()] = $tree;
            }
        } elseif ($node->isFile()) {
            $name = $node->getFilename();
            //if ('' == $regex || preg_match($regex, $name)) {
                $files[] = $name;

        }
    }
    asort($dirs);
    sort($files);
    return array_merge($files, $dirs);
}
```

Use like this:

```
$fileslist = dirtree('root');

echo "<pre style='font-size:15px'>";

print_r($fileslist);
```