# Print only specific file types in a directory and in numeric order in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Can anyone help me with edits to the following code to make it so that it only lists specific file types (png and jpg) and that it lists the files in the directory in numeric order (1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc)? Right now the code below will list any file type found in the directory and it prints them out of order even though all my images are named sequentially like 1.png, 2.png...

I have tried several things I found but just cant get it working right to only pull file types I define and print in numeric order based on the file name. Here is the code I have so far, which works other than these two issues I can't seem to solve. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
 $path = 'testimages';
$handle = @opendir('./' . $path . '/');
while ($file = @readdir($handle)){
if("." === $file || ".." === $file) continue;
echo ', {' . "\n" . ' id: ' . preg_replace("#\.[^\.]+$#", "", $file) . ',' . "\n" . 'name: "Product ' . preg_replace("#\.[^\.]+$#", "", $file) . '",' . "\n" . 'imageUrl: "' . $file . '",' . "\n"  . 'thumbnailUrl: "' .      $file . '",' . "\n"  . 'openUrl: "' . preg_replace("#\.[^\.]+$#", "", $file)         . '.html"' . "\n" . '}' . "\n";
}
 @closedir($handle);
  unset($handle,$file,$path);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the php function [glob()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php) for listing a directory.
You can apply the filter for image extensions right there.

I saw you tried to simulate a json output by appending strings. It's much easier to just write your data into a php array and then convert it using `json_encode`.

For the sorting you can use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php) which will let you define your own sorting function (in this case ascending numeric).

```
$path = 'testimages/';
$images = array();

foreach(glob($path.'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}',GLOB_BRACE) as $file){
    $filename = basename($file); // this will return just the filename without path
    $id = intval($filename); // this will turn for example 20.png into 20
    $images[] = array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>'Product '.$id, 'imageUrl'=>$file, 'thumbnailUrl'=>$file, 'openUrl'=>$id.'.html');
}

function imageSortASC($a,$b){
    return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
}

usort($images,'imageSortASC');

echo json_encode($images);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did some digging and found another solution too that seems to work. Is there any upside to your version verse this solution I posted below?

Comment: @Thomas No they basically do the same. Numeric sorting probably isnt guaranteed, but if scandir gives you the desired result, all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution I found that works for my needs. Thanks to original poster [Sort and display directory list alphabetically using opendir() in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884974/sort-and-display-directory-list-alphabetically-using-opendir-in-php)

```
<?php 
$path = "testimages";
$blacklist = array('firstlastimages','somefile.php');

// get everything except hidden files
$files = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($path)); 

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
      echo ', {' . "\n" . ' id: ' . preg_replace("#\.[^\.]+$#", "", $file) . ',' . "\n" . 'name: "Product ' . preg_replace("#\.[^\.]+$#", "", $file) . '",' . "\n" . 'imageUrl: "' . $file . '",' . "\n"  . 'thumbnailUrl: "' . $file . '",' . "\n"  . 'openUrl: "' . preg_replace("#\.[^\.]+$#", "", $file) . '.html"' . "\n" . '}' . "\n";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that will perform as desired.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/306891c7a742810fe80703b539fc30b1cb106568))

```
//$path="testimages";
//scandir($path));
$scan=[".","..",".htaccess","12.png","1.jpeg","somefile.jpg","somedir","10.jpg","2.png","firstlastimages.png"];
//var_export($scan);

// filter and sort
$files=preg_grep('/\.(?:png|jpe?g)$/i',$scan);  // only keep pngs, jpgs, and jpegs
$img_blacklist=['firstlastimages.png','somefile.jpg'];  // only blacklist non-png/jpg/jpeg files
$files=array_diff($files,$img_blacklist);  // filter out files in the blacklist array
//var_export($files);
natsort($files);  // Natural Sort -> order so that 2.jpg comes before 11.jpg
//var_export($files);

// store as indexed multidimensional array with associative subarrays
foreach($files as $file){
    $id=intval($file);  // removes the file suffix, casts as (int)
    $images[]=['id'=>$id,'name'=>"Product $id",'imageUrl'=>$file,'thumbnailUrl'=>$file,'openUrl'=>"$id.html"];
}
//var_export($images);
$json=json_encode($images);
var_export($json);
```

Here is what happens:

- For demonstration purposes, `scandir()` is replaced with a static array of test files and directories.
- `preg_grep()` filters out any element that doesn't end in `.png`,`jpg`,`jpeg` (case-insensitive). For this reason, no directories or `.php` files need to be blacklisted.  Only unwanted image files with a suffix of png/jpg/jpeg need to be listed in `$img_blacklist`.

  - To allow `gif` and `bmp` files, use this extended pattern: `/\.(?:png|gif|bmp|jpe?g)$/i` (reduce/extend as required).
- Rather than doing a blacklist check on every iteration of the `$files` loop, simply call `array_diff()` to filter them.
- `natsort()` is an existing php sorting function to sort values ASC and keep `2` before `10`.
- While looping the filtered `$files` array, the number in each filename is temporarily stored as an integer (not a string) `$id` using `intval()`.
- The output array (`$images`) is generated as per the OP's expected structure and then converted to JavaScript Object Notation using `json_encode()`.  It is not good practice to try to reinvent `json_encode()` (it is simply more work, and you may make a mistake).

Output:

```
'[{"id":1,"name":"Product 1","imageUrl":"1.jpeg","thumbnailUrl":"1.jpeg","openUrl":"1.html"},
  {"id":2,"name":"Product 2","imageUrl":"2.png","thumbnailUrl":"2.png","openUrl":"2.html"},
  {"id":10,"name":"Product 10","imageUrl":"10.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"10.jpg","openUrl":"10.html"},
  {"id":12,"name":"Product 12","imageUrl":"12.png","thumbnailUrl":"12.png","openUrl":"12.html"}]'
```

Points of difference:

- `glob()` with `GLOB_BRACE` is very handy for this task as it extracts filenames and filters by suffix in one step.  The only negatives (and these are no big deal) with using this function are that:

  1. the filter pattern is not the full functioning regex that you might expect -- read the notes under [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for more info on the syntax.  This means that the patterns can quickly become verbose/clunky.
  2. the return values will be prepended with their filepath, so if you only want the filenames, you will need to cut off the path.  (workaround: change your *current working directory* before calling `glob()`)
- Using `scandir()` requires an additional function call to filter for image files (compared to `glob()`).  The benefits of `preg_grep()` are:

  1. A brief regex pattern with the intuitive, predictable, and full-functioning PCRE syntax.
  2. The pattern can be extended to include more file suffixes or even to integrate the `$img_blacklist` values if desired.
- Using `natsort()` before `foreach()` spares a custom sort call.  `natsort()` doesn't alter the keys, but that is of no consequence because `$images[]` assigns new indices anyhow.